# How to make UIScrollView scrolling all content inside it

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have `UITextView`, `UIImageView`, `UILabel` inside `UIScroll` View. I made that `UITextView` height equals its content and made `scrollEnabled = false`. `UIScrollView` scrolling not all content. I want that `UIScrollView` scrolling all content inside it. I want to make `DetailViewController` as in news applications. How do I make it?

Comment: Why did you set `scrollEnabled = false`?

Comment: Because I want that UITextView is static and loaded all content at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solve, I ctr-drag from `UITextView` Height constraint to DetailViewController and made following

```
@IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint! {
    didSet {
        self.textViewHeight.constant = self.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.textView.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max)).height
    }
}
```